# Convex sets - metric projections

Tags: optimization, notation, convex-optimization, projection

In my course of optimization I got the following definition of metric projections

Let $\textbf{C}$  be a closed convex subset of a Hilbert space $\textbf{V}$ .

- For any $\textbf{x} \in \textbf{V}$, there exists a unique $\Pi \textbf{x} \in \textbf{C}$ such that
  $$
   \|\textbf{x} - \Pi \textbf{x}\| = \min_{y \in \textbf{C}}\|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\|
   $$
- $\textbf{y}_o \in \textbf{C}$ equals $\Pi \textbf{x}$ exactly when (iff)
  $$
   \langle \textbf{x}- \textbf{y}_o, \textbf{y} - \textbf{y}_o \rangle \leq 0 \text{ for all }\textbf{y} \in \textbf{C}
   $$
- If $\textbf{C}$ is a closed convex cone, then $\textbf{y}_o \in \textbf{C}$ equals $\Pi \textbf{x}$ iff
  $$
   \langle\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}_o, \textbf{y}_o \rangle = 0 \text{ and } \langle\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}_o, \textbf{y} \rangle \leq 0 \text{ for all } \textbf{y} \in \textbf{C}
   $$
- If $\textbf{C}$  is a closed linear subspace \textbf{V}, then $\textbf{y}_o \in \textbf{C}$ equals $\Pi \textbf{x}$ iff
  $$
   \langle\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}_o, \textbf{y} \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } y \in \textbf{C}
   $$
- For any two points $\textbf{x}_1$, $\textbf{x}_2 \in \textbf{V}$,
  $$
   \|\Pi \textbf{x}_1 - \Pi \textbf{x}_2\| \leq \|\textbf{x}_1 - \textbf{x}_2\|
   $$

Here are **my questions**:

- what does $\Pi$ represent? is it a scalar $\in \mathbb{R}$? is it something else?
- what does the notation $\min_{y\in \textbf{C}}$ exactly mean?
- what does $y_o$ represent? is it an element at the center of a Ball?

Answer (score 0):

$\Pi$, here, is supposed to be a mapping $V \rightarrow C$.

In the statements 2 to 4, $x$ is an arbitrary element of $V$ and $y_o$ an arbitrary element of $C$.

$\min_{y \in C} \|x-y\|$ is the smallest element of $\{\|x-y\|,\,y \in C\}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Mindlack. however it is stated that $y$ is an arbitrary element of $\textbf{C}$ (no necessarily $y_o$). What is the difference between $y$ and $y_o$?

Comment: $y_o$ is a “variable” that is “defined” prior to uttering statements 2-4. On the other hand, $y$ is a bound variable, which is a part of each statement. If you prefer, statement 2 means: if $x \in V$ and $z \in C$, and if for every $y \in C$, $\langle x-z,\,y-z\rangle \leq 0$, then $z=\Pi x$; on the other hand, if $x \in V$, then for all $y \in C$, $\langle x-\Pi x,\,y-\Pi x \rangle \leq 0$.